# Safari doesn't detect my Extension Certificate

Tags: safari-extension

I have registered for the Safari Development Program and have a valid Apple ID. I've followed all the steps given by Apple. 
The problem is that Windows XP (Service Pack 2) does not recognize the command 'certreq', whereas the instructions said it would work on any Windows machine.
However, the command 'certreq' was working on Windows Vista on the machine of my co-worker's, I downloaded the certificate (the .cer file) and installed it and Safari detected it.
However, I don't have Windows Vista.
I installed Windows 7 now on my machine, the command 'certreq' works and I have the Safari Extension Certificate (the .cer file) but when I open Safari's Extension Builder, my certificate does not appear there.

I entered mmc in Start --> Run and checked if the certificate was installed there. It was in the 'Other People' but not in 'Personal'.
Even on Internet Explorer 7+, when I go to Tools --> Internet Options --> Content (Tab) --> Certificates, the certificate is not there in the Personal tab, (WHEREAS IT GOT INSTALLED IN THE PERSONAL FOLDER AUTOMATICALLY IN WINDOWS VISTA). I tried importing the certificate (the .cer file) into the Peronal folder, the import is successful but still neither does it appear in the personal folder nor does Safari recognize/detect it when I go to the Extension Builder.

ANY HELP?!
I need to make an extension for my office project and the deadline is approaching. I really need to get it done.

Thanks a million in anticipation.

Comment: Maybe the good guys at superuser.com know better.

Comment: As this is such a specific question perhaps it is best addressed at Apple or the discussion forums at Apple.com?

Comment: Thank you. I've posted the problem on both places - superuser.com and discussions.apple.com for Safari Windows.
Still no reply on either of them.

Comment: Thanks all. I got it solved. But I can't really explain how. As I mentioned above, my certificate worked fine on Windows Vista and a couple of days later a co-worker of mine made a certificate on Windows 7 and, guess what, it's working now!

Comment: Cross-posted on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/154885/safari-doesnt-detect-my-extension-certificate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the similar problem. After struggling a lot the following worked for me:

1. Install (Windows Server 2003 service pack 2) Administration Tools pack as shown on “Generate a Certificate Signing Request” screen shown by Safari Extension Certificate assistant: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=6315
2. Install IIS resource kit for SelfSSL- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=17275
3. As indicated by Safari Extension certificate assistant, save the following as certreq.txt --https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/safari/files/certreq.txt
4. Run `cmd`, and then change directory to where you saved certreq.txt
5. On command prompt type: `certreq –new certreq.txt newcsr.pem`
6. Press *Continue* on the Safari Assistant screen, and upload this newcsr.pem
7. It will generate a certificate that you need to install by double-clicking on the installed file.

You are done!

Go to Develop (in Safari menu bar)>> Show Extension Builder >> Click + and select new extension.

Comment: Critical step is the installation of SelfSSL for Windows XP without which it doesn't work: Install IIS resource kit for SelfSSL- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=17275

Comment: step 3, Safari indicated no such thing. Thanks, though - just what I needed

Answer (score 5):

By generating the cert request on another machine you don't have the private key associated with the cert on your own.  Generate a cert request on your Win7 machine now, go get a new cert from Apple, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To use the certificate on Windows, I needed to click on the file that was created (safari_identity.cer).  That installed the certificate in the Windows Certificate store.  Rrun certmgr.msc and look under the Personal..Certificates folder to see it.  My installed cert  looked something like this in the Microsoft Management Console for Certificates:  "Safari Developer: (xxxxxxxxxxx) me@zzz.com".

Answer (score 1):

this is an answer for Mac users who may be experiencing this problem.

Once you install your certificate, double click it, go under Trust, and set Always Trust for When using this certificate. Your certificate should work then.

Answer (score 0):

It's got something to do with the private key - On me Vista it says CertReq: Request Created and it installs fine, but then on Windows 7 it just creates the file and when you look at the info before/after install it doesn't display that it is associated with the private key on the computer. Very confused I am.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the info" when you say, "...when you look at the info before/after install it doesn't display..."
Mine worked. I'm not sure how. But my certificate was working on Windows Vista but not on Windows 7. Then my fellow-employee created his certificate on Windows 7, did nothing special but the instructions by Apple, and guess what, his certificate works! He didn't even provide his private key. It just appears in the Extension Builder.
I recommend you make a fresh certificate from Apple website and install it on THE SAME Operating System and machine where you make it.

Answer (score 0):

when you enter something like "certmgr.msc" in the run command in window, you will get to see something like this:

So using the certificate consists of the following steps:

1. first save the file and run the command in cmdd.exe as directed in the developer certificate generator in extension certificate developer.
2. when you are done, check the certmgr [shown above in the image] and see a certificate named safari developer installed somewhere near Certificate Enrollment Requests. cut the certificate and paste one copy inside trusted root certification Authorities and another inside Personal.
3. then generate the csr file and install the file inside Personal folder and trusted root certification Authorities folder.
4. extension builder will recognize the certificate.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate has an incomplete chain, it may be necessary to install the certificates on Apple's [certificate page](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) .  I believe "Worldwide Developer Relations" (and possibly the 2 root certificates) are necessary for Safari Development.

Comment: Although it's true that the certificate chain is incomplete by default, I was not having any issues with registering the certificate. Yet Safari did still not recognize it.