# How to generate a CSR file on windows 7 for safari extension development?

Tags: safari-extension, csr

All blogs refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/certificates/index.action) page to the create certificate but the page no longer contains the instructions to create csr file on Windows.

I remember that the instructions was there some time ago. Does it mean that they no longer support the certificate creation on Windows?

Comment: I would not be surprised, considering the last version of Safari for Windows was 5.1.

Comment: A Windows solution may be kind of pointless going forward. Just got Apple email that Safari dev program will be merged into Apple (iOS/Mac) dev program, which is $99/yr just to release/publish official Safari extensions (to the gallery). This applies to extension updates as well. At that price, may as well get a Mac and build iOS and/or Mac apps too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions in this answer [Safari Extension Developer Certificate - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011066/safari-extension-developer-certificate-windows#answer-17455861) works for Windows. Follow the instuctions carefully and you won't have to do anything else to make it work on Windows 7